# Incrementing program counter on branch address

Tags: architecture, mips, cpu-architecture

How do I increment the program counter using a MIPS instruction? I have the code below:

```
if (R[rs] > 0)
    R[rs] = R[rs] - 1
else
    PC = PC + 4 - Branch Address
```

So far I think this works:

```
 slt $t0, $rs, $rt #This is a pseudoinstruction translation for R[rs] > 0
 bne $t0, $zero, ELSE 
 add $rs, $rs, -1 #add -1 to $rs to decrement
Else:
                  #do something here: Maybe jump to branch address? jr branch address How to get branch address?
```

Comment: Why not put a label between the BNE and ADD and use a J LABEL immediately after the ELSE label?

Answer (score 0):

```
 slt $t0, $rs, $rt #This is a pseudoinstruction translation for R[rs] > 0
 bne $t0, $zero, Else 
 add $rs, $rs, -1 #add -1 to $rs to decrement
 b endif
Else:
 # do the else
endif: 
 # rest of the program
```